# Why is the blue background behind the usernames of the nominees not present unless one presses the "add/show comments" button?

Tags: support, comments, moderator-election

Whenever I comment under my question or to an answer posted on my question, I notice a blue background behind my user name like this:

[image]

- Why doesn't this background appear when [viewing the nominees who are contesting the election](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1)?
- Why does it appear only when pressing the <kbd>add a comment</kbd> or <kbd>show x more comments</kbd> buttons?

Note that pressing <kbd>add a comment</kbd> won't trigger this behavior on small comment threads where there isn't a <kbd>show x more comments</kbd> button as [@l4mpi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1110381/l4mpi) [points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289878/why-is-the-blue-background-behind-the-usernames-of-the-nominees-not-present-unle#comment174920_289878).

Comment: +1, saw that yesterday as well. It's probably a hack attached ot the "show more comments" function because the CSS class is usually reserved for the question OP. And in my case it does _not_ appear when clicking "add a comment" on small comment threads where no comments are hidden by default and thus there is no "show more comments" link.

Comment: Oh yeah. I forgot to mention that pressing "add a comment" won't trigger this when there isn't a "show x more comments" button...

Comment: [Duplicate of a duplicate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289719/960757)...

Comment: D'oh, I'm sorry. The deleted post I've linked was mine. Martijn Pieters found and mentioned there this SE meta post http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220611 (hence that deletion).